# gnu make: rule execution order

Tags: gnu-make

I am reading https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf. On page 24 it says

```
OBJDIR := objdir
OBJS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,foo.o bar.o baz.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c                    #first rule
   $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)                   #third rule

$(OBJDIR):
   mkdir $(OBJDIR)
```

*Now the rule to create the objdir directory will be run, if needed, before any ‘.o’ is
built*

I do not understand why the directory will be created first?? When target *all* is created, it looks at the prerequisite *$(OBJDIR)/foo.o*... and for this prerequisite both rules apply: the first and the third rule. Why is the third rule executed before the first rule? How does make decide in general which rule to apply first if two or more rules apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$(OBJS): | $(OBJDIR)
```

says that all object files (in the `OBJS` variable) have the directory (in the  `OBJDIR` variable) as a prerequisite.

Therefore, none of the object files can start to be built until after the directory rule has completed.

If there are multiple rules (only one can have a recipe of course) then all the prerequisites are combined into a single list.  In your example, you could also write it this way:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJDIR)
            $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

and it would be equivalent.